# changing my interface to handle new requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have importers encompassing logic for different data structures that need to import data from files. So far, they implement my IImporter interface:

```
public interface IImporter {
   string[] Header {get;}
   List<object> ImportData(File file);
}
```

Then I can use IoC in my controllers to pass in the interface and make it testable:

```
public FileAController(IImporter AImporter)
...
public FileBController(IImporter BImporter)
...
```

Also I pass this interface around to some other classes which reference the Header property for some logic.

Now however, another import file type has been introduced, but this also requires some additional context, let's say an ImportPreference, which determines the header and also the import logic. However, I can't implement the current IImporter interface, and I don't want to change the interface method to take in an extra parameter since it's only going to be used for this specific importer.

I have looked at the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example), but I am not sure how to apply it to my specific case. How can I make this change without impacting my current interfaces and classes?

Comment: I am assuming there is a current `ImporterA` implementation. You are thinking of adding a new `ImporterB` implementation which needs some extra stuff that `ImporterA` doesn't. Is that right? Also, do you want `FileAController` to work with **either** implementation? Or does `FileAController` really need a `ImporterA` to work correctly? _I am asking these questions to clarify whether you need one interface with two implementations, or two interfaces with one implementation each._

Comment: Each controller only corresponds to one FileImporter. So ControllerA will only need to work with ImporterA.

Comment: In that case, have two different interfaces.

Comment: Your new interface `IImporterExtended` can **inherit** from `IImporter`. So you can pass `ImporterB` that implements `IImporterExtended` into a method that expects `IImporter`.

Comment: But that means that all the classes that Implement IImporterExtended, have to implement List<object> ImportData(File file); as well as List<object>ImportData(File file, ImportOption option);

Comment: Ok but then how can FileBController which only has a reference to IImporter do that since IImporter doesn't have that property, FileBImporter class does?

Comment: `FileBController` will need a reference to `IImporterExtended`.

Comment: Ah interesting. Didn't think of that! I'll try that and let you know. Thanks mate.